# one sentence of "if"

Tags: tense, past-tense, clauses, future-tense, subordinate-clauses

Now, I'm talking about the past, something I'm not quite sure. (not the unreality)

> At that time,  if he took part in the meeting on the next day, maybe he was preparing the speech.

Is this sentence grammatical?

Comment: I'd use *he would be preparing the speech* instead.

Comment: The question is not clear. But it seems that you ask about **Conditional Sentences**. See here https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/conditional-sentences and try to focus on what conditional are you talking about.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to say?

Are you guessing, that he might have prepared the speech on the condition that he partook in the meeting the day after? If that's the case, it would be clearer if you moved "at that time" to the phrase it belongs to.

"If he took part in the meeting on the next day (Tuesday), maybe he was preparing the speech at that time (Monday)."

Answer (score 0):

I take it that it was unknown whether the man was participating in the meeting next day or not.  Anyway, if he was, then he had or was willing to do it and that is why the speaker thought he might be busy at that time, preparing his speech for the meeting.

So my suggestion is to add modality to both the main and if - clauses to make the sentence more readable:

> At that time, if he had (was/was going) to take part in the meeting
>   next day, he might be preparing his speech.